# Why does String.replace not work?

Tags: java, string, replace

I am a little bit confused at the moment. I tried that:

```
String test = "KP 175.105";
test.replace("KP", "");
System.out.println(test);
```

and got:

```
KP 175.105
```

However, I want:

```
175.105
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You did not assign it to `test`. Strings are *immutable*.

```
test = test.replace("KP", "");
```

You need to assign it back to `test`.

Comment: You have no idea how much anguish you saved me. TYSM

Comment: not working for "...",""

Answer (score 22):

`Strings` are immutable so you need to assign your `test` reference to the result of `String.replace`:

```
test = test.replace("KP", "");
```

Answer (score 7):

String is immutable in java so you have to do

```
test =test.replace("KP", "");
```